# Why does this not work when I make it an app?

Tags: applescript, startup

Why does this not work when I make it an app? Im trying to make this work but all it does is keystroke the commands in finder not terminal. It even works in the applescript editor just not as an app. Please help!

```
on run
    tell application "Terminal" to quit
    delay 5
    tell application "Terminal" to activate
delay 3
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using {command down}
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "top" & return
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using {command down}
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "open -a Bartender" & return
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "open -a MobileMouseServer" & return
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "open -a gfxCardStatus" & return
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "open -a Caffeine" & return
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "open -a Alfred" & return
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "open -a smcFanControl" & return
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "w" using {command down}

tell application "Finder" to display dialog "System startup successful." with title "T.R.A.V.I.S." with icon file "Macintosh HD:SCRIPTS:ICNS:travis.icns" giving up after 5
end run
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider using the `do shell script` command instead of using a Terminal window: `do shell script "open -a Bartender"`, `do shell script "open -a MobileMouseServer"`, etc.

Comment: Or to use `tell application X to activate` to launch programs: `tell application Bartender to activate`, `tell application MobileMouseServer to activate`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this structure:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen

    -- targets an existing window
    do script "top" in window 1

    -- open a new window
    do script "open -a Bartender"

end tell
```